# Non Intel AVD emulator

Tags: android, x86-64, android-virtual-device, amd

Environment:

Android Studio v3.2.1 latest build Oct2018

Emulator version 28.0.20 Dec 2018

HAXM V7.3.2

Non intel Avd Image Nougat (7.1.1) Api level 25, arm64-v8a

Command line to start avd:

```
C:\Android_sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_2_API_25arm -verbose -accel on -engine auto -gpu off -netspeed full -netdelay none -logcat '*:s
```

where the following options can be applied:

```
rem options for  -gpu: auto, host, swiftshader_indirect, angle_indirect, off
rem options for -engine: auto, classic ,qemu2. (classic=qemu1)
```

I have tried all options and combinations (eg -engine classic is invalid for non intel)
but performance is atrocious.

Does anyone has any tips on how to make this avd run such that working with it becomes at least possible.

My other question is a long shot. I need an amd image to run Poweramp (android music app) but am unable to install.

any help appreciated

Comment: is it this app com.maxmpz.audioplayer in the play store?

Comment: yes it is. I am trying to develop a new skin for it. Also I have a playlist manager app which is closely integrated with poweramp

Comment: so I guess you just need to download an apk with the x86 library then, I just tried to download one from [this site](https://apk-dl.com/) and it runs on an x86 emulator

Comment: You probably did not install the latest version of poweramp. Anyway, you should download from the ooweramp site.

Comment: I don't, really, what I mean is that it seems that the app does support x86 architecture